# How to make a text entry fields move up when on screen keyboard is present

Tags: android

How to make a text entry fields move up when on screen keyboard is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) on the [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/index.html) covers several options for dealing with layout issues when an on-screen input method editor is visible.

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea :

you could use the `getHeight()` method from inputmethodservice.Keyboard to get the height of the softkeyboard on the screen, and then add a minus margin to your `EditeText`?